# Does local strict contractibility imply ANR?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Say that a space (= compact metrizable space) $X$ is locally strictly contractible if, for every $p\in X$ and neighborhood $U$ of $p$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ which can be contracted to $p$ within $U$ relative to $p$, i.e. by a homotopy leaving $p$ fixed.  (This may be bad terminology, and I welcome alternatives.)

Every ANR is locally strictly contractible.  What about the converse?  Borsuk's example of a locally contractible space which is not an ANR is not locally strictly contractible.

Incidentally, "locally contractible" is defined in different ways in various references.  What is the currently accepted definition?

Comment: A space is generally defined as 'locally P' if there is a neighbourhood basis with each element of the basis having property P. What you have is probably called locally _relatively_ contractible (as is a special case of 'locally relatively P', which refers to a property of the _inclusion_ map of the elements of the basis), or even "$V\to U$ is nullhomotopic as a _pointed_ map".

Comment: Borsuk's definition of "locally contractible" is the same as the one I gave of "locally strictly contractible" without the "relative to $p$" part.  A stronger definition sometimes used is that $X$ is locally contractible if every point has a neighborhood base of contractible open sets.  By this stronger definition even an AR is not necessarily locally contractible.

Comment: Yes, the contractibility of the open sets as spaces or in their own right, or as subspaces is an important distinction that is not often emphasised. It is a pity there is not a more systematic notation.

Comment: David: where does your notion of 'locally P' come from? Is it something originating in algebraic geometry, or just someone's philosophy? I haven't ever seen it used in topology (in the rare event that people need it, they just say 'has P neighborhoods of points'), and I suppose in geometric and general topology there's nearly a century-long tradition of using 'locally P' in the sense of appropriately many neighborhoods (normally one for each quantifier).  

Comment: Bruce: beware that 'strictly contractible' does have another meaning in the literature, not unrelated to yours: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864101000086

Comment: Thanks.  Not really being a topologist (although we operator algebra people sometimes like to think our subject includes topology as a special case), I'm not always up on correct topology terminology or the topology literature.  What name do you suggest for the property I describe?

Comment: Upon some reflection, Borsuk's example does actually seem to be, hmm, pointed locally contractible. It's an interesting question though if there exists a locally contractible compactum that is not pointed locally contractible. It would have to be infinite-dimensional. As for Borsuk's example, it is not locally equi-connected in the sense of Fox and Dugundgi (or equivalently, not uniformly locally contractible in the sense of Isbell). A long-standing open problem which has considerable literature is whether local equi-connectedness is equivalent to the ANR property for compacta. 

Comment: See also http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1983-087-01/S0002-9939-1983-0677252-6/

Comment: OK, I see my mistake in analyzing Borsuk's example.  But the concept of local equiconnectedness seems to be the right one for the work I am currently doing, rather than pointed local contractibility.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I guess I still don't see how to contract Borsuk's example to, say, the point with $x_1=0$ and $x_n=1/2n$ for $n>1$.  It seems that any contraction of a neighborhood has to send this point via a point with $n$'th coordinate 0 or $1/n$ for some $n>1$.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this point $x$. Some points $y$ in a neighborhood of $x$ (namely, those with $1/k>y_1>1/(k+1)$) would have to traverse a region $R_k$ consisting of points $z$ with $z_k=0$ (only for a while, not until the end of the homotopy). But for $y$ to be in a neighborhood of $x$, $y_k$ must be bounded above by an $\epsilon_k$, where $\epsilon_k\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. So the motion of $y$ towards $R_k$ and through $R_k$ becomes smaller and smaller as $y\to x$, and then it doesn't force $x$ to move.

Comment: The problem is that to contract a neighborhood, you have to be able to work in a coordinate $m$ for which the neighborhood doesn't hit both ends of $X_m$, so points can be moved around one end.  But for any neighborhood of the point $x$, there are only finitely many such coordinates to work with, so the end you move around can't be passed off to infinity.  (Hope this cryptic description makes sense.)

Comment: I'm assuming $X_m$ is the boundary of the cube $[1/(m+1),1/m]\times [0,1]^m\times\{0\}^\infty$. Then 'both ends' could mean $\{1/(m+1),1/m\}\times[0,1]^m\times\{0\}^\infty$ or it could mean $[1/(m+1),1/m]\times[0,1]^{m-1}\times\{0,1\}\times\{0\}^\infty$. The latter two sides shouldn't be of concern for any point $x$, and the former one would be of concern for an $x$ that lies close to the cube $Q_m=\{0\}\times [0,1]^m\times\{0\}^\infty$, but far from its boundary. Your $x$ is about as close to $Q_m$ as to its boundary, for *each* $m$. Every $x$ has only finitely many $Q_m$'s to worry about.

Comment: Our notation seems to be different.  I was using Borsuk's notation where the Hilbert cube is the product over all $n$ of $[0,1/n]$.  In your notation the point $x$ has first coordinate 0 and all other coordinates 1/2.  By the two ends of $X_m$ I meant the end with $x_m=0$ and the end with $x_m=1/m$ (Borsuk's notation).

Comment: This space is a sort of multidimensional version of the infinite comb space (or, more accurately, the infinite ladder), where to contract everything must be moved through a corner point.

Comment: OK, so Borsuk could be using the $l_2$ metric, and I'm more comfortable using the notation where the infinite product is endowed with the inverse limit metric (as the inverse limit of the finite products). So your $x$ would be (0,1/2,1/2,...) in my notation. A basic neighborhood of this point is of the form $U_i=[0,1/i]\times \prod_{j=i}^0[\frac12-2^{-j},\frac12+2^{-j}]\times [0,1]^\infty$. It meets the sphere $X_m=\partial([1/(m+1),1/m]\times [0,1]^m\times\{0\}^\infty)$, where $m\ge i$, in a subset of the belt $\{1/(m+1),1/m\}\times[1/4,1/4]^i\times [0,1]^{m-i}$. (to be cont'd)

Comment: (Starting from the above formula for the belt, I'm dropping the infinite tail of zeros.) All of this belt can be pulled down towards, and then into the subset $\{1/(m+1),1/m\}\times [1/4,1/4]^{i-1}\times\{0\}\times [0,1]^{m-i}$ of the face $[1/(m+1),1/m]\times [0,1]^{i-1}\times\{0\}\times [0,1]^{m-i}$ of the cube with boundary sphere $X_m$ (so this face lies within the sphere). This motion is entirely along the $(i+1)$st coordinate, so it moves each point at most by $1/(i+1)$. As a result, we've taken the belt off the cube's waist, and once we pull a part of it across the bottom of the cube,

Comment: by a motion that is entirely along the segment [1/(m+1),1/m] of the first coordinate, nothing obstructs pulling it further towards $x$, by a linear homotopy.

Comment: Bruce, I now see that you were right. The motion I've described is of the order of $1/i$ but it affects points that about $(1/m)$-close to $x$. Here $m$ could be large, so for the homotopy to be continuous, $x$ has to move as well. Sorry for taking your time, and thank you for explaining Borsuk's example, which as you see I didn't quite understand.

Comment: This is a tricky (but worthwhile) example to understand.  I'm still not sure I could write out a rigorous proof of what I claimed, but I'm pretty sure it's right.